# What is the yellow warning sign in the "Login Items" Tab under the "Users & Group" System Preferences?

Tags: login-items

I was deleting Skype from my login items and noticed that iTunesHelper showed a warning under a unmarked column. What does it mean and how do I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The yellow warning sign means that the login item can no longer be found, most likely because the application was deleted or moved after it was added to the login items. If you hover your cursor over the triangle, it will tell you:

[image]

To re-add iTunesHelper:

1. Find iTunes in /Applications
2. Right-click on it, and select "Show Package Contents".
3. Navigate into Contents, and then MacOS
4. Drag iTunesHelper into your Login Items in System Preferences
5. Check "Hide" to hide it on launch (this may not be necessary, but it's how iTunes sets it up)

Comment: Thanks, any suggestion on how to fix it, for example with iTunesHelper?

Comment: @SteveMoser Yep, just edited my answer with instructions

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept after the 5 min waiting period. I wish the waiting period wasn't necessary but it makes sense.

Comment: It seems that hovering over it in macOS Sierra no longer says what the reason is for the warning triangle.  I guess we should just assume it always means the file is missing?

Answer (score 0):

In High Sierra, it's often a permissions problem (e.g., Fastscripts tries to add itself, which is somehow not allowed). If you know where to find the application, delete the one with the warning and drag in a new one manually.