# Item: "Documents", Kind "Unknown" in Login Items

Tags: macos, system-settings, login-items

In my Login Items on Mac OS 10.11.3 I see an item called "Documents". The Kind is specified as "unknown" and there is a yellow warning sign at the end of the line.

No further information is shown when I hover or click the warning sign or the item. I checked the loginwindow.plist, but couldn't see anything relating to the item in question.

I don't want to [merely clear it out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47040/what-is-the-yellow-warning-sign-in-the-login-items-tab-under-the-users-grou).

Does anyone know what this item is supposed to do and how I could further inquire what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow or another it sounds like your Documents *folder* was added to your startup items. I *think* this used to be a way to have the Finder open a specific folder on login, but it hasn't worked that way for some time.

It is not serving any purpose now, and there's no reason to keep it.